# Summarize counts based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to get a summary of my data based on combinations of two variables.
The following code used to work on the data:

```
df <- data_frame(fc = runif(1000, -5, 5),
           padj = runif(1000, 0, 1))

df %>% 
  summarise(
    dn_red = count(fc < -1.5, padj <= 0.1),
    dn_pink = count(fc < -1.5, padj >= 0.1),
    dn_blue = count(fc>-1.5 & fc< 0, padj <= 0.1),
    dn_grey = count(fc>-1.5 & fc< 0, padj >= 0.1),
    up_red = count(fc > 1.5, padj <= 0.1),
    up_pink = count(fc > 1.5, padj >= 0.1),
    up_blue = count(fc < 1.5 & fc > 0, padj <= 0.1),
    up_grey = count(fc < 1.5 & fc > 0, padj >= 0.1)
  )
```

Running it after a couple of months since writing it throws the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `dn_red`.
x no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "logical"
ℹ Input `dn_red` is `count(fc < -1.5, padj <= 0.1)`.
```

I can see that count outputs a tibble with logical vectors corresponding to the conditions. What I am trying to get out of it is a summary of the counts, where both the conditions are TRUE. The code above used to do just that...

Comment: to count logical vectors you can use `sum` instead.  However, you are using `,` instead of `&` in the code and that's why it'll create some overlaps.  So it is advisable to create a colors variable and have its `count()` afterwards.  Not sure what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perhaps want `sum` instead of `count`!

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(fc = runif(1000, -5, 5),
                 padj = runif(1000, 0, 1))

df %>% 
  summarise(
    dn_red = sum(fc < -1.5, padj <= 0.1),
    dn_pink = sum(fc < -1.5, padj >= 0.1),
    dn_blue = sum(fc>-1.5 & fc< 0, padj <= 0.1),
    dn_grey = sum(fc>-1.5 & fc< 0, padj >= 0.1),
    up_red = sum(fc > 1.5, padj <= 0.1),
    up_pink = sum(fc > 1.5, padj >= 0.1),
    up_blue = sum(fc < 1.5 & fc > 0, padj <= 0.1),
    up_grey = sum(fc < 1.5 & fc > 0, padj >= 0.1)
  )

  dn_red dn_pink dn_blue dn_grey up_red up_pink up_blue up_grey
1    494    1250     269    1025    458    1214     267    1023
```

But this is creating overlaps.  So you need to replace `,` within logical conditions with either `&` or `|` as the case may be.  See.

```
df %>% 
  summarise(
    dn_red = sum(fc < -1.5 & padj <= 0.1),
    dn_pink = sum(fc < -1.5 & padj >= 0.1),
    dn_blue = sum(fc>-1.5 & fc< 0 & padj <= 0.1),
    dn_grey = sum(fc>-1.5 & fc< 0 & padj >= 0.1),
    up_red = sum(fc > 1.5 & padj <= 0.1),
    up_pink = sum(fc > 1.5 & padj >= 0.1),
    up_blue = sum(fc < 1.5 & fc > 0 & padj <= 0.1),
    up_grey = sum(fc < 1.5 & fc > 0 & padj >= 0.1)
  )

  dn_red dn_pink dn_blue dn_grey up_red up_pink up_blue up_grey
1     44     328      20     127     40     296      18     127
```

If this is what you expected, then it is advisable to divide `1000` data points into eight colors. Use this code instead

```
df %>% mutate(new = case_when(
  fc < -1.5 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'dn_red',
  fc < -1.5 & padj >= 0.1 ~ 'dn_pink',
  fc > -1.5 & fc < 0 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'dn_blue',
  fc > -1.5 & fc < 0 & padj >= 0.1 ~'dn_grey',
  fc > 1.5 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'up_red',
  fc > 1.5 & padj >= 0.1 ~ 'up_pink',
  fc < 1.5 & fc > 0 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'up_blue',
  fc < 1.5 & fc > 0 & padj >= 0.1 ~ 'up_grey',
  TRUE ~ 'others'
)) %>% count(new)

      new   n
1 dn_blue  20
2 dn_grey 127
3 dn_pink 328
4  dn_red  44
5 up_blue  18
6 up_grey 127
7 up_pink 296
8  up_red  40
```

or better use `janitor` to have a frequency count

```
df %>% mutate(new = case_when(
  fc < -1.5 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'dn_red',
  fc < -1.5 & padj >= 0.1 ~ 'dn_pink',
  fc > -1.5 & fc < 0 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'dn_blue',
  fc > -1.5 & fc < 0 & padj >= 0.1 ~'dn_grey',
  fc > 1.5 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'up_red',
  fc > 1.5 & padj >= 0.1 ~ 'up_pink',
  fc < 1.5 & fc > 0 & padj <= 0.1 ~ 'up_blue',
  fc < 1.5 & fc > 0 & padj >= 0.1 ~ 'up_grey',
  TRUE ~ 'others'
)) %>% janitor::tabyl(new) %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals()

     new    n percent
 dn_blue   20   0.020
 dn_grey  127   0.127
 dn_pink  328   0.328
  dn_red   44   0.044
 up_blue   18   0.018
 up_grey  127   0.127
 up_pink  296   0.296
  up_red   40   0.040
   Total 1000   1.000
```

Comment: That yield different results (counts exceed the total observations, too). Here is an example: `df %>% summarise(dn_pink = sum(fc < -1.5, padj >= 0.1))` gives 1233, while `df %>% count(fc < -1.5, padj >= 0.1)` returns 316, when both conditions are TRUE.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to substitute the `,` with `&`.